# webpack configuration to concatenate all files in a directory to a single file

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to switch from brunch.io to webpack and I want to keep current layout as follows:

- index.html
- app.js (concatenate all files in app/ dir)
- vendor.js (concatenate all files in dep/ dir)

I have a success with `index.html` and `app.js` files so far, but I couldn't manage to concatenate files in `dep/` folder into `vendor.js`

Here is my webpack.config file:

```
  var webpack, compileDir, jsEntryPoint, jadeEntryPoint;
  require("shelljs/global");
  webpack = require('webpack');
  compileDir = "./build";
  jsEntryPoint = "./src/client/init.ls";
  jadeEntryPoint = "./src/client/static/index.jade";
  echo("clear build directory");
  rm('-rf', './build/*');
  module.exports = {
    entry: [jsEntryPoint, "file?name=" + compileDir + "/index.html!jade-html?with=pretty!" + jadeEntryPoint],
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: compileDir + "/app.js"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.ls$/,
          loader: 'livescript-loader'
        }, {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("./src/dep", compileDir + "/vendor.js")],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".ls"]
    }
  };
```

How can I concatenate all files in `dep/` folder into `vendor.js`?

Comment: Do `app` files refer to `vendor` directly? What's the relation between those?

Comment: I am no expert in Webpack. I have achieved what you ask by: (1) adding an extra entry point: `entry: { ..., vendor: ['the vendor files']}` (2) using the `CommonsChunkPlugin` as: `plugins: [new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */'vendor', /* filename= */'vendor.bundle.js'), ...]`. Note the 1st argument to `CommonsChunkPlugin` is the name of the entry point.

Comment: This isn't really how webpack is meant to work -- grunt/gulp are a better fit for what you describe. The 'webpack way' is to specify dependencies within your application code via `require`, and let webpack handle bundling those modules as needed. Keeping files in a certain directory and forcing webpack to bundle them together, you're losing out on its dependency management and forcing the dev(s) to be responsible for it.